# c:\windows\assembly\temp eats all our diskspace

Tags: .net, gac

We have a server where we have many development enviroments.
We have since this spring (4 months) had issues with the c:\windows\assembly\temp folder never cleans itself.

Today the size is ~28gb of the folder it self.(out of our 80gb C: disk)

All threads i've read comes back to that the temp folder should be a "self cleaning" directory

This is the most linked blogposts about GAC and it's temp folders:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/17/gac-temp-and-tmp.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/f728af5e-c13f-48bc-ab60-0e6f1886321c/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/10/24/484063.aspx

using the gacutil.exe /cdl seems to only clean the c:\windows\assembly\tmp folder. =(

Now to my question: How can I clean this directory?

**UPDATE:**

I have not found a permanent solution to this. so far I have manually deleted the c:\windows\assembly\temp folder when it grows too big. not all files are possible to delete, because they are in use.

Still I would love to hear why this is happening.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer anywhere to this? I'm seeing the same problem. I keep getting out of disk space warnings because it's taking up 27gigs of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you - I too had to manually delete all the folders in the **C:\Windows\Assembly\Temp** directory. Nothing is broken, as far as I can tell.

I first tried doing it the "Microsoft way" with **GACutil.exe** (obtained from a VS installation), which said it completed successfully, but did NOT do anything.

In my case the **TMP** directory does not exist, only the **TEMP** directory exists.

This is on a computer running Windows 10 LTSC 1809 b17763 x64, updated to latest sub-build as of today. Guess I'll be using a script to handle that. Too bad it does not clean automatically, like it should.

**NOTE:** I should mention that I performed a ResetBase, DiskCleanup and switched to CompactOS mode. Maybe one of those procedures led to those folders sticking around...